# Add "Content-Diposition" to post axios request

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to post a file to a remote server using axios post request.
I want to add "Content-Disposition" param to the req header.

This is the code, I've been using so far:

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function makePostRequest() {

    data = {
        id: 15,
        first_name: 'Fred',
        last_name: 'Blair',
        email: 'freddyb34@gmail.com'
      }

    headers = { 
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachement' 
    }
    let res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/users/', data, headers);

    console.log(res.request._header);
}

makePostRequest();
```

I want to have this param available in the metadata params of the uploaded file.
This is the result I've got:

```
POST /users/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
User-Agent: axios/0.21.0
Content-Length: 79
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: close
```

**Content-Disposition** is missing.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: It's up to the server to add the header. You can't add it from the client-side.

Comment: Why are you trying to add `Content-Disposition` to the *request*? It is not usually used there.

Comment: I want to upload a file to an AWS S3 bucket, I need to add this header param.

Comment: This is the code I am using :                                                                                          ```                                                                                                                                  var ContDispoValue = 'attachment';
    return axios.post(resp.url, resp.formData,  {
      headers: {
        'Content-Disposition': ContDispoValue
      }})                                                                                                                               ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument to `post()` is an Axios configuration object, not a headers object. `headers` is a property of the config.

```
const headers = { 
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachement' 
};
const config = { headers };
let res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/users/', data, config);
```

---

`console.log(res.request._header);` won't do anything though. There's no such property on an XHR object.

---

NB: While this will set the header, it is highly unlikely that the server will do anything with it unless you are written custom logic for it to do so. `Content-Disposition`, according to [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) is a **response** header when used in HTTP.

Comment: do you think that it is possible to add this param with a get request from a server? Thanks.

Comment: While a piece of software can act as both an HTTP client and an HTTP server, if it is making a GET **request** it is being a client. It can add whatever headers it wants to the request it makes. Adding a `Content-Disposition` header to an HTTP request still doesn't make sense. The client can't control what headers the server that generates the response adds to that response.

Comment: `Content-Disposition` is not just a response header:

"An example of an HTML form posted using the multipart/form-data format that makes use of the Content-Disposition header:"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition